# Easiest way to sort XML in Python? [Skype Bot]

Tags: python, xml, bots, skype, skype4py

I'm making a Skype bot and one of my commands is `!trace ip_or_website_here`

However, I see to be having an issue sorting out my XML Responses.

`Commands.py`:

```
elif msg.startswith('!trace '):
    debug.action('!trace command executed.')
    send(self.nick + 'Tracing IP. Please Wait...')
    ip = msg.replace('!trace ', '', 1);
    ipinfo = functions.traceIP(ip)
    send('IP Information:\n'+ipinfo)
```

And my `functions.py`:

```
def traceIP(ip):
    return urllib2.urlopen('http://freegeoip.net/xml/'+ip).read()
```

Now, my issue is that responses look like this:

```
!trace skype.com
Bot: Tracing IP. Please Wait...
IP Information:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Ip>91.190.216.21</Ip>
<CountryCode>LU</CountryCode>
<CountryName>Luxembourg</CountryName>
<RegionCode></RegionCode>
<RegionName></RegionName>
<City></City>
<ZipCode></ZipCode>
<Latitude>49.75</Latitude>
<Longitude>6.1667</Longitude>
<MetroCode></MetroCode>
<AreaCode></AreaCode>
```

Now, I want to be able to make it work without having the XML Tags.

More like this:
IP Address: ip
Country Code: CountryCodeHere
Country Name: countrynamehere
and so on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is good for parsing XML.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> xml = urllib2.urlopen('http://freegeoip.net/xml/192.168.1.1').read()
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)
>>> soup.ip.text
u'192.168.1.1'
```

Or in more detail..

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ip  = "192.168.1.1"

xml = urllib2.urlopen('http://freegeoip.net/xml/' + ip).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)

print "IP Address: %s" % soup.ip.text
print "Country Code: %s" % soup.countrycode.text
print "Country Name: %s" % soup.countryname.text
```

Output:

```
IP Address: 192.168.1.1
Country Code: RD
Country Name: Reserved
```

*(updated to latest `BeautifulSoup` version)*

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I get an import error.

'from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup'

I use Python 2.7 btw.

Comment: Check out the download page, you need to download and install the module... http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/#Download

Comment: Yeah, I know that much. I just tried to uninstall/re-install it. 
Still same error.

Comment: **wait** I got it. Thank you for the help :) I had to install BS3 instead of BS4. My mistake.

Comment: ah!  I was just checking on possible installation errors!  glad it helped ;)

Comment: Use VirtualEnv to install Python libraries: http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/